# java.beans.VetoableChangeListener cannot be resolved

Tags: android, class, graph, compiler-errors, jfreechart

```
The type java.beans.VetoableChangeListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I'm trying to use a `XYDataset` with `XYSeriesCollection` from `JFreeChart` in my Android APP but getting this error in eclipse.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing on Android, you should use [AFreeChart](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/), which is a charting library for Android, inspired by JFreeChart.

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake is to believe that just because Android uses the Java language, any Java code can run on it.

Android implements only a subset of the JavaBeans API. Looking at the official Android [`java.beans`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/beans/package-summary.html) documentation, the class JFreeChart depends on is not listed in there.

Comment: Can I fix this by implementing the required classes from java.beans? Or are there any other simple possibilities to create a line chart?

Comment: You probably could. I also heard some people had success by using the Apache Harmony implementation of the JavaBeans on Android.